# What's the best way to define a nested class / object / enum structure in Java?

Tags: java, class, enums, nested

I'm working on an Android App (Java) which uses the API of a Yamaha Blu-ray Player via HTTP POST. The player has a strict command set in XML format. Commands follow a hierarchy: while most of the outer XML elements are always the same, the structure inside belongs to the type of player function. For example, the play/pause/stop functions have the same path in XML, while skip functions have other parent elements. You can see what I mean in the following code example.

```
public enum BD_A1010 implements YamahaCommand
{
    POWER_ON ("<Main_Zone><Power_Control><Power>On</Power></Power_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    POWER_OFF ("<Main_Zone><Power_Control><Power>Network Standby</Power></Power_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    TRAY_OPEN ("<Main_Zone><Tray_Control><Tray>Open</Tray></Tray_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    TRAY_CLOSE ("<Main_Zone><Tray_Control><Tray>Close</Tray></Tray_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    PLAY ("<Main_Zone><Play_Control><Play>Play</Play></Play_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    PAUSE ("<Main_Zone><Play_Control><Play>Pause</Play></Play_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    STOP ("<Main_Zone><Play_Control><Play>Stop</Play></Play_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    SKIP_REVERSE ("<Main_Zone><Play_Control><Skip>Rev</Skip></Play_Control></Main_Zone>"),
    SKIP_FORWARD ("<Main_Zone><Play_Control><Skip>Fwd</Skip></Play_Control></Main_Zone>");

    private String command;

    private BD_A1010 (String command)
    {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public String toXml ()
    {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><YAMAHA_AV cmd=\"PUT\">" + this.command + "</YAMAHA_AV>";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried the flat enum way, which works fine. I can use the enums with my RemoteControl class just like that:

```
remoteControl.execute(BD_A1010.PLAY);
```

The enum's .toXml() method returns the full XML code needed to send to the player. Now here's my problem: I need a better way to build the function hierarchy in Java classes. I want to use it like that:

```
remoteControl.execute(BD_A1010.Main_Zone.Power_Control.Power.On);
```

Like nested enums or classes. Each level of the command should define its XML element inside itself. Also, each command on a path may only define the sub-commands that are possible: for example, after Main_Zone.Play_Control I may only use .Play or .Skip, not .Tray or anything else. At the end of the chain I like to call .toXml() to get the full XML command.

**What is the best way in Java to define this hiarachy as (nested) classes?** Should be easy to define - as little code as possible.

Later, it should be possible to merge two or more commands to get a combined XML like the following - but that is not so important for the first try.

```
remoteControl.execute(
    BD_A1010.Main_Zone.Power_Control.Power.On,
    BD_A1010.Main_Zone.Play_Control.Skip.Rev,
    BD_A1010.Main_Zone.Play_Control.Play.Pause
);

<Main_Zone>
    <Power_Control>
        <Power>On</Power>
    </Power_Control>
    <Play_Control>
        <Skip>Rev</Skip>
        <Play>Pause</Play>
    </Play_Control>
</Main_Zone>
```

Comment: what is a problem to do as you described, I mean to nest enum to another enum?

Comment: Also, Does YmanaCommand interface define toXml method?

Comment: As far as I know, nested enums are not possible in Java, are they?

Comment: Yes, YamahaCommand interface defines toXml(), so I can create different enums, one for each device.

Comment: why not, it's possible to nest enum to another enum(it will be treated as static inner class). In fact nested enum in any(class, interface enum) context will be treated as static inner class

Answer (score 6):

Why does it have to be enum? [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to the rescue.
Consider this flavour: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/creating-and-destroying-java-objects-par/208403883?pgno=2 instead of vanilla one. The core improvement is very readable syntax:

```
builder.withProperty(...).withFeature(...).finallyWith(...)
```

Comment: I agree, a good example you can find in Kerievsky's "Refactoring to Patterns" - "Encapsulate Composite with Builder" (p. 96 - 113)

Comment: Not bad, I will consider it. Thanks!

Comment: @BertKößler could you please tell us how you solved you problem after all?

Comment: @pavelrappo I didn't solve it. I stay with the flat enum style in my first example.